# Putting NSArray into TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, azure

I'm having trouble transferring data from my NSArray to populate my Table View. I've looked around and tried a few different things, but no luck so far.

**Here is my code:**

```
#import "ListFilmController.h"
#import <WindowsAzureMobileServices/WindowsAzureMobileServices.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ListFilmController ()


@end

@implementation ListFilmController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
}
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MSClient *client = [(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]     client];

MSTable *itemTable = [client tableWithName:@"filmbuff"];

[itemTable readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
    else {
        _allFilms = items;
        NSLog(@"Item inserted, array: %@", items);
    }

}];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this     view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_allFilms count];;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier     forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text=[_allFilms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

I pull the array data from Azure and transfer it to an array. Now I want it so that every cell is a different row from that array. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Are you sure the `_allFilms` array is being populated with data?

Comment: `readWithCompletion` is an async task, your tableview could be loading before you have data

Comment: You could try to initialize your _allFilms array before the "readWithCompletion" line. After that, in the completion block where you are assigning "items" to "_allFilms" you should add something like "[_myTable reloadData];". At this point, your _allFils array is already populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simon has the answer in a comment. I'm going to re-post it as an answer. (@SimonMcLoughlin, you should really do that so you can get the accepted answer credit).

In your viewDidLoad method, you're firing off an async request. That request won't  be filled until some time later.

In the meantime, your app is displaying the table view. The table view calls the various data source methods and is told that there are no cells to display.

What you want to do is to add a `[myTableView reloadData]` call to the end of your completion block:

```
[itemTable readWithCompletion:
^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
    else {
        _allFilms = items;
        NSLog(@"Item inserted, array: %@", items);
        [myTableView reloadData];
    }
}];
```

That will cause the table view to re-query the data source methods `numberOfSections`, `numberOfRowsInSection:`, and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and display the new content in the table view.

You might also want to add a message or progress indicator of some kind so the user knows that the app is fetching data from a remote server. You would display the message/progress indicator when you start the async request, and then remove it in the completion block, just before calling `[myTableView reloadData]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of understanding your problem. I think I would do something like this:

```
#import "ListFilmController.h"
#import <WindowsAzureMobileServices/WindowsAzureMobileServices.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ListFilmController ()


@end

@implementation ListFilmController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
}
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MSClient *client = [(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]         client];

MSTable *itemTable = [client tableWithName:@"filmbuff"];

// Your app will not crash if it tries to populate the tableview before you get the data
_allFilms = [NSArray new];

[itemTable readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {

if (error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
else {
    _allFilms = items;
    // After populating your data array you will have to reload the table view data
    [_tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Item inserted, array: %@", items);
}

}];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, had to change a couple of things but this worked. It was loading the array after the table view.